# Drawing the level curve of $x^2-y^2$

Tags: calculus

To do this, my professor solved for $x^2-y^2 = c$ when $c = 0$, $c > 0$ and $c < 0$. Why these particular values?

I know how to draw the curves for those values I don't understand why zero in particular.

Comment: $c=0$ gives a very interesting result.  Why not simply do it and see?  What other values of $c$ could even *possibly* be interesting?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Define "interesting"

Comment: The lines from $|x|=|y|$ split the plane into four quadrants in which the function has the same basic (allowing for minus sign) behaviour. So you only need to do a quarter of the work if doing it manually :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just solved the simple problem you'd see why the contours for $c=0$ are  "interesting":  They are straight lines (!!) amidst everywhere curved surfaces.

[image]

Fascinating!

What a terrible shame:  You ask others to solve this trivial problem for you and to reveal what is interesting rather than have the self-reliance and joy of discovering a little mathematical result on your own.

Too bad.

Comment: When you put it that way it does sound kind of interesting!

Answer (score 2):

If the equation had been $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2 + 3$, then $f = 0$ would *not* have been an interesting level-set ... instead, $f = 3$ would have been interesting. Why is it interesting? Well, it's really because $x^2 - y^2$ *factors* into a product of linear terms, namely $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y )(x+y)$, and when $uv = 0$, one of $u$ or $v$ must be zero, so the plot is a pair of straight lines.

This is more generally true: if you're hoping to plot level-sets for a polynomial $f$, you'd like to find values $c$ such that $f(x, y) - c$ actually *factors*, because those will generally be the "interesting" ones (the ones where the topology of the level sets change in some way, typically).

As for this example, how did the prof *know* that $c = 0$ was special? Presumably she'd worked out the problem previously (or chose the values to make $c = 0$ special). That was (presumably) done as a way to set up this experience for you, so that you could make the leap to saying "Hey, what happened there? How did the left-and-right-pointing hyperbolas become up-and-down-pointing hyperbolas? What the heck is going on here?" Of course, that sort of experience and "aha! moment" only work for those willing to have the experience.